# I am looking for advice on how to speed up a program I wrote to generate a large 2d array of prime numbers mod a subset of the primes

Tags: python, numpy, math, primes, sage

I am using numpy, and sagemath for next_prime(). Could i get significant boosts from using a lower level language? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
length = 99
width= 9
primeArray = np.empty(length,dtype=int)
primeArray[0]=2
for i in xrange(1,length-1):
   primeArray[i]=next_prime(primeArray[i-1])
primeMods = primeArray[1:width+1]
primeModArray =np.empty([length,width],dtype=int)
for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(length):
        primeModArray[y][x] = primeArray[y]
output = np.mod(primeModArray,primeMods)
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n)

Comment: I would just do it all in Sage, personally, as it would have arbitrary (up to your memory) sized primes.

Comment: Do you know if sage has a vectorized mod function like numpy?

Comment: Using prime_range instead of next_prime might help.

Comment: Thanks William. I added a seive and it helped a lot. I will try Sage's primerange when i get home. It didn't come up when i searched the documentation for a sieve. Now the computation of mods dominates prime generation with just the first 10 mods. I guess i need to find a faster mod function and creat a numpy ufunc with it. The sage support said "Maybe you're looking for a matrix over a finite field?

http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/finite_rings/sage/rings/finite_rings/finite_field_constructor.html
 also look at the matrix( ... ...) function." i will try one of those . Any tips?

Comment: Actually it is the duplication of the prime array that takes all the time even with just 19 copies

Comment: primeArray=np.array(prime_range(limit))
    length= primeArray.shape[0]
    time1 = time.time()
    primeMods = primeArray[1:width+1]
    primeModArray =np.empty([length,width])
    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(length):
            primeModArray[y][x] = primeArray[y]
    time2 = time.time()

    output = np.mod(primeModArray,primeMods)
    time3 = time.time() 
    print output
    print primeModArray.shape
    print time1-time0
    print time2-time1
    print time3-time2

(664579, 19)
0.345091104507
21.3867900372
0.969210863113

Comment: sorry. point is it takes .34 seconds to generate 664k primes, 21 seconds to make 19 copies and only 1 second to calculate 6664k * 19 mods